# copy file from network shared drive to desktop using DOS copy command in Javascript

Tags: javascript, batch-file, command, dos

I am looking for the code, where i need to copy file from network shared drive to desktop using DOS copy command in javascript. As sample code below:

**Sample Code:**

```
oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

oShell.ShellExecute(cmd.exe, copy C:\text123.txt D:\folder\, "", "open", "1");
```

Comment: Genuine question: why? If you're using JS, just use Node's API; there is zero reason to use "a dos command" or the code you're showing. On the other hand, if you *need* DOS (which technically you don't, DOS hasn't existed for decades, you probably mean the Windows Command Prompt) then why not just use a .bat file or something?

Answer (score 0):

From Help for your language.

```
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

fso.CopyFile ("c:\\mydocuments\\letters\\*.doc", "c:\\tempfolder\\")
```

What is wrong with your code is the cmd syntax is wrong. Type `cmd /?`.